# Dynamic Distribution List

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm looking to create a Dynamic Distribution List with a custom filter to look at the job title and that the account is enabled. I've tried the following but unfortunately i cannot use the wildcard at the beginning of title. I'm trying to capture users who have a job title of "Teacher - staff" but the teacher bit could be variable and so want to capture the staff part.

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup "AllEmployees" -RecipientFilter {((Title -eq '*staff') -and (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and -not (UserAccountControl -eq "AccountDisabled, NormalAccount"))}
```

Comment: Try replacing the `-eq` comparison for `-like`. Using the `-eq` will look for the exact value and not consider the wildcard.